# WCF Service Project Runs In Debug, but Crashes in Release

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, wcf, release

I am trying to run my project in Release mode, and I'm running into a problem:  I crashes immediately with this exception:

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.ServiceModel.ProtocolException' occurred in 
mscorlib.dll

Additional information: The content type text/html; charset=utf-8 of the response message 
does not match the content type of the binding (text/xml; charset=utf-8). If using a 
custom encoder, be sure that the IsContentTypeSupported method is implemented properly. 
The first 1024 bytes of the response were: 
    '<!DOCTYPE html>
     <html>
      <head>
       <title>Could not load file or assembly 'MyNamespace.MySolution.MyProject' 
        or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an 
        incorrect format.
       </title>
```

The inner exception is a `(500) Internal Server Error.`

I've tried launching the release version in the debugger and stepping into the code right before that error, but I can't step into the code any further - it doesn't offer to attach to the server process, and just throws the error.  I've seen several similar questions, but nothing seems to address this issue.  I'd appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: I don't think you can debug release version code (but I'm not 100% certain).  The error message seems to be pretty clear though - "Could not load file or assembly 'MyNamespace.MySolution.MyProject' 
        or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an 
        incorrect format."

Comment: Did you change runtimes? It could be that you were working in `Debug` configuration that's `x86`, and your `Release` configuration is `x64`. I bet it's that, or one of your dependencies is set up like that.

Comment: This is probably not really it, but just in case:  the response is *html*, but the binding is *xml*

Answer (score 0):

As Tim has correctly pointed out that service is throwing error possibly due to a missing assembly.

Most likely cause could be that one of the assembly referenced in the service project is missing in the 'Release' configuration.